# Is drifting analog common problem of PSP? How to fix it?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, psp

I have bought a secondhand PSP (E1004 Street) a few weeks ago. Generally, this handheld works well, but after a few days of casual playing (max 2h per day) I see a little problem - the analog is drifting, mainly to the right, so in some action/platform games it could be deadly - controlled character can fall down from various places.

I had another PSP some years ago and I clearly remember that I had the same problem then. It was PSP Fat 1004 model. I broke it completely when I tried to fix this issue. So I have a question - is it a common problem that analog drifting to any side? How to avoid that? Or maybe I have a lot of bad luck and I just bought a problematic PSP twice?

I also tried to calibrate it by entering to System settings->System Info and rotating analog, but I read somewhere in the web that then should appear the rotating circle, the same as appears when something is loading, but I did not see it.
I read also about replacing some rubber from under analog to the new one - does anybody do it? Did it help?

EDit: It seems, that in some games it occurs very rarely, in some others it has never happened, but in another, it makes it impossible to navigate even in the main menu - caret jumping through all of the options (in practical game characters almost always move in a random direction without touching analog by me).

Comment: IGN has a really in-depth article about controller drift, which basically boils down to all modern analog stick designs are the same, and suffers the same problem. I'm not sure it pertains to the PSP, but I would guess it does. Here's the article https://nordic.ign.com/feature/45005/the-real-science-behind-controller-drift